# Initial value of the DropDownList should be blank

Tags: vb.net

I have a Dropdownlist "Servers" which gets populated by the below code during form load event. The database in the connection string, has a list of Server names which get populated without any issue using the below code.

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Populate_Server()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Populate_Server()
    Dim query As String = "select ServerName, ServerId from Server_Names"
    BindDropDownList(DropDownList_Server, query, "ServerName", "ServerId", "")
End Sub
```

Next, I have another dropdownlist "Instances". Data to be populated into this ddlist is on another server/database. So, depending on the previous selection (ddlist_server) I'm populating data as shown in below code:

```
Public Sub Populate_Instance()

    Dim State As String
    Dim ConnectString As String
    Dim SelectSQL As String
    Srv = DropDownList_Instance.SelectedItem.Text
    DropDownList_Instance.Items.Clear()


    ConnectString = "Data Source=" & Srv & ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=true"

    Using Con As New SqlConnection(ConnectString)
        Con.Open()
        SelectSQL = "Select * from Instance;"

        Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SelectSQL, Con)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
        Do While dr.Read = True
            DropDownList_Database.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
        Loop
        'DropDownList_Database.DataBind()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Instances ddlist gets populated successfully but the first value, is thefirst   record in the table, but my requirement is this to be blank. The reason being, I want to do Server Side Validation as shown in the below code:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="req1" runat="server" Style="top: 85px;
        left: 378px; position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 160px" Font- Bold="True" Font-Names="Trebuchet M S" Font-Size="Small"
        ControlToValidate="DropDownList_Instance" validationgroup="Info"
        ErrorMessage="Select an Instance" InitialValue=0>
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I require your assistance on making the first entry blank in `ddl_Instance` or validating `ddl_Instance`

Comment: Just do `DropDownList_Database.Items.Add("")` before your `Do While`loop

Comment: Thanks for your time Pikoh, that worked. But the ddl_database validation does not show "Select a Database" message, when the ddlist entry is blank and after button click. Please advise.

Comment: Add InitialValue="IdOfBlankItemAdded" to the required field validator

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pikoh stated.

```
DropDownList_Database.Items.Add("", "0")
```

To add the blank item.

Then change your reuqired field validator so it knows the Initial Value by adding.

```
InitialValue="0"
```